# Using an advice to redirect to login controller handler method

Tags: spring, aop

I have this use case of wanting to use an AOP advice to check user login and redirect to a login handler if user has not logged in.
What i couldn't figured out is how the advice will return a value to the login handler method of the controller. 
Any ideas ?

Comment: Don't use AOP, use a `Filter` or `HandlerInterceptor`... Or even better don't try to get security right yourself but use Spring Security instead.

Comment: @Deinum thanks for your comment.  But the idea is to always check user login status once a user clicks on a certain link. So you mean AOP is a bad idea for this ?

Comment: And why wouldn't that be possible with a filter and as mentioned Spring Security already solves that problem for you... Why reinvent your own...

Comment: Hmmm, Ok let me look at the Spring security. I really am not familiar with it. Thanks anyways

Comment: Still you don't need AOP you can simply do it in a servlet `Filter` or Spring `HandlerInterceptor`. You can concern both methods as AOP for web :)